# Uniquely determine the two parameters of a distribution given pre-determined probabilities for two disjoint subsets of its support

Tags: probability, density-function, cumulative-distribution-function, distributions, mathematical-statistics

Let $F(x| \alpha, \beta)$ denote the cumulative density function of a probability distribution. Let $[a,b]$ and $[c,d]$ be two disjoint subsets of the support of $F$. Suppose that  $F(b) - F(a) = p$ and $F(d) - F(c) = q$, for some non zero $p$ and $q$ such that $p + q < 1$. Can you always uniquely determine $\alpha$ and $\beta$? Otherwise, under what conditions/probability distributions can you determine the parameters?

For examples:

1) $F$ is the normal distribution, and $F(0) = 0.4$ and $F(1) - F(0) = 0.3$. Can you uniquely determine the mean and standard deviation?

2) Consider the [skew normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution), with probability density function
$f(x| \xi, \omega, \alpha) = 2\phi(\frac{x-\xi}{\omega})\Phi(\alpha \frac{x-\xi}{\omega})$. If we fix the location $\xi$, can we uniquely determine the scale $\omega$ and skew $\alpha$ under conditions set out above?

Comment: sorry, i slightly abused the word 'disjoint' as clearly in example one the subsets $(-\infty, 0]$ and $[0, 1]$ are not disjoint. Please pardon the sloppiness in the definition here.

Comment: Have you ever seen (or sketched for yourself) a normal density curve? If you have, and have paid any attention to the details, the datum $F(0)=0.5$ is wiggling its eyebrows and winking an eye, and pointing out with suggestive movements of its elbow and shoulder and thumb, the value of the mean to you.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right, that is a bad example, I will change it.

Comment: This note is relevant: http://www.johndcook.com/quantiles_parameters.pdf . It shows how to solve this problem for the normal, log normal, Cauchy, Weibull, gamma, and inverse gamma probability distributions.

Comment: These questions are related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30236/is-there-a-method-to-estimate-distribution-parameters-given-only-quantiles, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6022/estimating-a-distribution-based-on-three-percentiles

Comment: Your definition 2 doesn't work as it stands, since the way you define it there, $f$ is the same for any $\mu,\sigma$.

Comment: thanks @Glen_b, fixed now. Anyway, by the linked paper, I suppose the answer to 2) is also yes, since the skew normal distribution forms a location scale family.

Comment: This question appears to be too general to admit any complete and useful answer.  Once it is rephrased rigorously, it asks under what conditions a function $f:\mathbb{R}^k\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is one-to-one. The function in question maps the parameters $\theta\in\mathbb{R}^k$ to the ordered pair $(F([a,b]),F([c,d]))\in\mathbb{R}^2$. In statistical practice $f$ is continuous and obviously its image lies in $[0,1]\times[0,1]$, but these conditions are too weak to do anything with.

Comment: Hi @whuber. Appreciate you taking the effort to phrase the question rigorously and in generality. In my case I would like $k = 2$ (i.e. 2 parameters). The question arose as a parallel to solving a system of linear equations: given two pieces of consistent (probability) information, is possible to uniquely determine 2 unknown parameters. I hope that those of you more knowledgeable about exotic distributions can come up with a counter example if you feel this statement is not true. Alternatively, statements like, this is true for all unimodal, continuous distributions are also very good...

Comment: ... and at least John Cook (as linked) believes this is useful enough to produce an answer given specific distributions.

Comment: Nobody's denying the potential utility.  I would just like to suggest that you consider narrowing your question. It doesn't take an "exotic" family of distributions to produce a counterexample: the procedure can fail for just about any family, depending on how $a,b,c,d$ are chosen.  Generically, though, it will succeed for any one- or two-parameter family and will necessarily fail for any family with more than two parameters.

Comment: it would be really helpful if you could provide such a counter example as I am finding it very difficult to imagine that this result is not true, at least for a unimodal distribution.

Answer (score 2):

For your first example,
$$F(0) = \Phi\left(\frac{0-\mu}{\sigma}\right) = \Phi\left(\frac{-\mu}{\sigma}\right) = 0.4$$
and so
$$-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}= \Phi^{-1}(0.4) \approx -0.2534\tag{1}$$
while 
$$F(1) = 0.7 = \Phi\left(\frac{1-\mu}{\sigma}\right)$$
and so
$$\frac{1-\mu}{\sigma}= \Phi^{-1}(0.7) \approx 0.5243\tag{2}$$
and you *should* be able to calculate the values of $\mu$ and
$\sigma$ from $(1)$ and $(2)$.

Comment: yes, this forms a system of linear equations and the initial conditions forces it to be a consistent system.